# Looking for novel. Lobster like creatures sailing on a high gravity planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

What I remember is alien creatures sailing a modular ship on a planet with very high gravity. I think the planet was doughnut shaped. They sailed to a region with lower gravity and witnessed another race of their species flying some sort of gliders.

The genre is Hard Science

The book was published sometime in 50s I think

Comment: Any chance you remember any more details? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more points it may help you remember. Such as when you read it, when it was published, etc.

Comment: "The genre is Hard Science." Not that hard, if it's got large lobster-like aliens in a high-gravity environment. The maximum size at which exoskeletal organisms are viable drops off dramatically with an increase in intensity of gravity. IRL earth lobsters are basically the result of bugs evolving in a lower-gravity environment (as the buoyancy in the water effectively simulates a lower gravity than is actually present).

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Good info, but this question didn't say they had exoskeletons or were particularly large at all.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon: Though I believe the limit is at least partially based on oxygen levels; if the planet's atmosphere was also highly oxygenated, the scaling issues with exoskeletal designs could be (at least partially) mitigated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not quite. There are two separate limitations at work in the sorts of creatures we tend to most associate with exoskeletons (arthropods). The oxygen thing isn't actually directly associated with the exoskeleton; it's a limitation of the type of respiratory system that happens to be featured by the particular exoskeleton-users we're most familiar with. The gravity one is the limitation on arthropod size that's actually directly exoskeleton-related: the drawbacks of an exoskeleton get dramatically worse, and the benefits drop off, the bigger you get.

Comment: @zabeus Good catch. I have no idea where I got the idea the OP was about lobster-like creatures. Don't even remember what else I was doing that day, to look for things I might have confused this with.

Comment: Ah. Found it: there was an edit the same day as my edit that took out the reference to them being lobster-like. Was earlier in the day than my comment, but apparently I'd had the question sitting open on my computer for a while before I got around to reading and responding to it.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Well it does still say that in the title so that's understandable. :) As we can see they were in fact like both lobsters and centipedes!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

About the nearest match I can think of is Hal Clement's [*Mission of Gravity*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1511). The   planet, Mesklin, has a polar diameter a lot less than its equatorial one, and it rotates very fast, so that gravity at the poles is around 700g, but only 3g at the equator.

The main discrepancy is that, iirc, the natives resembled centipedes rather than lobsters, but memories (including mine) are imperfect, and cover illustrations don't always match the text, so that mismatch isn't necessarily conclusive.

In *MoG*, the ship is called the *Bree* and the Captain's name is Barlennan. Does either of those names ring a bell?

Comment: They definitely had a lot more claws than centipedes do...

Comment: There's a plot description at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_of_Gravity) for *Mission of Gravity*.

Comment: A version of the novel was published as a 4-part serial in *Astounding* which is available at the Internet Archive: [part 1](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v51n02_1953-04_starhome), [part 2](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v51n03_1953-05_cape1736), [part 3](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v51n04_1953-06_starhome), [part 4](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v51n05_1953-07_starhome).

Comment: I would suspect those names of being lifted from the barkeep and the location of the Prancing Pony, if it wasn't for the fact that Mission of Gravity was published marginally *before* The Fellowship of the Ring.

Comment: Maybe Tolkien did the lifting...

Comment: They did indeed encounter other natives that used gliders

Comment: Also, *Bree* was a raft in segments -- raft because "hollow boats" collapse inward in very high gee, segments to allow reconfiguring for ocean and river travel.

Comment: From MoG: "and had taken advantage of near-weightlessness to rear al-most his full length upward from the deck. It was still a fantastic sight to see him towering, balanced precariously on his six rear-most legs," and "getting a grip with his front pincers, releasing the hold of his rear ones, and twisting his caterpillar-like body forward " and "a body fifteen inches long and two in diameter crawling horizontally " and "the hearts in each of his body segments pumping furiously"

Comment: From *Star Light* the sequel: "The captain watched critically as they wriggled their long bodies and numerous legs into the transparent envelopes" and "His arms and legs were carefully relaxed, chelae neither too tightly closed nor gaping open, his head neither too high nor too close to the floor, his eyes fixed steadily on the screen."  A "chela" is a pincer-like claw.  They were both lobster-like and centipede-like.

Comment: @hobbs: Years ago I asked Hal Clement, and he told me that he did not read LotR until after MoG was published. And we know Tolkien wrote about Barliman and Bree long before Clement had even started MoG, so it is definitely an amazing coincidence.

Comment: It happens that way sometimes. Fifty years ago, Arthur C Clarke and Poul Anderson simultaneously published stories about solar sail propulsion, and both used the same title, "Sunjammer".

Comment: @MikeStone: I don't consider that one very striking. Solar sails were an idea kicking around at the time, I don't think either Clarke or Anderson invented them, and "Sunjammer" is  title that follows very logically from the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Dragon's Egg by Robert L Forward also features creatures living in a high-g environment (the surface of a Neutron Star).

80s rather than 50s, I'm afraid, and it's been a long time since I've read it so I can't recall whether it's what you're looking for, but might be worth an investigate.

Comment: The neutron star natives, however, were more like ameobae who could grow crystalline bones when needed, than like lobsters (or centipedes with claws, as in *Mission of Gravity*).  There was no sailing in *Dragon's Egg* (at least until the Cheela developed space travel of their own)-- no standing liquid on the degenerate matter crust of the titular neutron star.

Comment: A great book though!

Comment: A wonderful book, but I must point out that even as a science-nerd adolescent, I noticed that the Cheela had remarkably human personalities. Well, one can't have everything.